# Java, LDAP, ADAM - How do I create a container with a forward slash in the name

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

I am having trouble writing some Java code, which will create a container/folder in ADAM, where the container name and distinughed name contain a forward slash.
e.g.
    cn=test/test
    dn=CN=test/test,CN=TestStore,DC=MyCompany,DC=COM

```
LdapContext _ctx = getNewContext(valid_userName, valid_userName, valid_userName);
  // uses InitialLdapContext under the hood 

String containerDN = "dn=CN=test/test,CN=TestStore,DC=MyCompany,DC=COM"
_ctx.createSubcontext(containerDN, attrs); // assume attrs is valid javax.naming.directory.Attributes
```

I am struggling to escpae the forward slash from the Java String object, and yet allow the InitialLdapContext to create the container with the name.

FRom the ADAM Adsi Edit application, I can create folders with forward slashes, so I presume the process can be done from code as well.

Many thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-reading the JavaDocs API for LDAPContext, and DirContext ... an overloaded method createSubContext() offers:

```
public DirContext createSubcontext(Name name, Attributes attrs) throws NamingException
```

the Name interface, concrete class CompositeName handles the escaping/un-escaping of special characters for me ...

many thanks JRL !

Answer (score 0):

From [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc977992.aspx), might be of use:

> If the name of an organizational unit
>   contains a forward slash character
>   (/), the system requires an escape
>   character in the form of a backslash
>   () to distinguish between forward
>   slashes that separate elements of the
>   canonical name and the forward slash
>   that is part of the organizational
>   unit name. The canonical name that
>   appears in Active Directory Users and
>   Computers properties pages displays
>   the escape character immediately
>   preceding the forward slash in the
>   name of the organizational unit. For
>   example, if the name of an
>   organizational unit is
>   Promotions/Northeast and the name of
>   the domain is Reskit.com, the
>   canonical name is displayed as
>   Reskit.com/Promotions/Northeast

Comment: Thanks, 
I have been reading through: http://java.sun.com/products/jndi/tutorial/beyond/names/syntax.html  
and have been trying variations of backslashes escapes:  
String containerDN = "dn=CN=test/test...";  
String containerDN = "dn=CN=test\/test; \\errorInvaliudEscapeChar  
String containerDN = "dn=CN=test\\/test";  
String containerDN = "dn=CN=test\\\\/test;  
String containerDN = "dn=CN=test\\\\\\/test";  
String containerDN = "dn=CN=test\\\\\\\\/test";   


All to no avail ...

Comment: @DeclanWilson: in the link you've provided, it talks of composite names... could this have to do with it?